# how to change default variant name of smartFilterBar in ui5 (i.e. 'standard ' to 'custom')?

Tags: sapui5

I want to change the variant name of   smartFilterBar from  'standard'(default variant name) to 'custom'(some custom name which shows instead of 'standard' ). when app initialise at first .

Answer (score 1):

Why should you do this? The SmartFilterBar control including its variant management allows the user to define any variant and set the flag "default" to it which will result in this custom variant being loaded on init. If you add some logic like you suggest, you would invalidate this feature and your users will be confused why the variant that he/she selected is not taken.

Comment: Thanks ,but i  just wanted to change the name of standard variant  from 'standard' to some other name(say 'view'), means i don't want to load any other custom variant and just wanted to change the name of standard variant.

Comment: Tough question since I do not know how the SmartFilterBar variant checks for duplicate names. Since the variant name is stored in a database, the uniqueness will also be stored there. If you change this on-the-fly on the UI, you may end up with duplicate names on the UI and possible unforeseeable side effects by this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SmartVariantManagement, there is a property called '[standardItemText](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smartvariants.SmartVariantManagement%23controlProperties)', using which you can set any new name.